# Recursive python function to look for directory

Tags: python, recursion, time

I am trying to find files in a directory, if not there wait for 10 minutes and check again endlessly, and once i have the files in return path to the calling program.

I want to do in a clean recursive manner and i am not good at recursion so will need the community help.

calling function will call something like this

```
path = self.find_dir(path,dir_name)
```

The function itself i want to be like

```
def find_dir(self,path,dir_name):
try:
   #my logic to look for dir and do other checks 
   #will be here   
except Exception, Err:
   sleep(self.wait_time)
   #after waiting then call the function again
   find_dir(self, path , dir_name)
```

I am sure this will not work  but can someone help me find a way i can make this kind of structure to work like this.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: unless it is just exercise, use `os.path.walk`.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, upon re-reading his post

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use a while loop?

```
def find_dir(self, path, dir_name):
    while True:
        try:
            #your logic
            return True
        except SpecificExceptionNotJustError:
            sleep(self.wait_time)
```

Using recursion on a possibly endless code may cause you to exceed the recursion limit of your system, and should be avoided in this case. Also, you should check for the *specific* error you excpect, not just `Error`. Only checking for `Error` may hide flaws in your code, and should **always** be avoided.

Comment: If you don't use a while loop, you risk hitting the maximum recursion limit (although if you sleep for 10 minutes, that won't happen for a very long time)

Comment: Agreed @Simon, I was just editing that in while you were posting your comment :)

Comment: Thanks a lot!. Much easier way to implement this way. thanks!!

Comment: Recursion is great for solving certain types of problems, such as depth first search or divide and conquer type of problems. However, most problems are better solved with a loop if possible (and tail recursive functions can be turned into loops).

Answer (score 0):

`while` loop will do the job. [`os.walk()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) walks through a directory recursively for you. Here is the skeleton:

```
def find_dir(self, path, dir_name):
    while True:
        try:
            for root,dirs,files in os.walk(dir_name):
                if path in root:
                     return True
            raise FileNotFoundError
        except FileNotFoundError:
            sleep(self.wait_time)
```

The above code snippet will return True until path exists in the dir_name.

If you're checking for files or multi-entities, just change the code.

Answer (score -1):

If you insist on recursion, it looks basically fine, you just have to return something. Since Python doesn't do tail call elimination, you wouldn't be able to monitor indefinitely. A while loop would not have that shortcoming.

Comment: Technically he does not need to return anything. What he has will do fine, so long as the function has side effects (which in practice is bad). So he does not **have to** return anything, although it would be better to do so.